# Jest mocking a function within another function

Tags: node.js, mocking, jestjs

I have searched quite a bit, and whilst there are many questions asked about mocking functions, none of the solutions I've found work for my setup, and I'm not quite sure why. I have the following:

***questionnaire-service.js***

```
const service = require('./request-service')();

function questionnaireService() {
    function createQuestionnaire() {
        const opts = {
            url: `http://some-url.com`,
            body: {
                data: "some-data"
            }
        };
        return service.post(opts);
    }

    return Object.freeze({
        createQuestionnaire
    });
}

module.exports = questionnaireService;
```

***request-service.js***

```
const got = require('got');
const merge = require('lodash.merge');

function requestService() {
    function post(options) {
        let opts = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            json: true,
            body: options.body
        };
        opts = merge(opts, options);
        return got(opts.url, opts);
    }

    return Object.freeze({
        post
    });
}

module.exports = requestService;
```

I am trying to write tests for the questionnaire service, and want to mock the 'post' function. I have tried the following

***questionnaire-service.test.js***

```
const requestService = require('./request-service')();
const questionnaireService = require('./questionnaire-service')();
const createdQuestionnaire = require('./test-fixtures/res/get_questionnaire.json');

describe('questionnaire service routes', () => {
    it('Should create a new questionnaire', async () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(requestService.post);
        spy.mockReturnValue(createdQuestionnaire);

        const response = await questionnaireService.createQuestionnaire();

        expect(requestService.post).toBeCalled();
        expect(response).toMatch(createdQuestionnaire);
    }

    it('Should create a new questionnaire', async () => {
        jest.doMock('./questionnaire-service', () =>
            jest.fn(() => ({
                createQuestionnaire: () => createdQuestionnaire
            }))
        );

        const response = await questionnaireService.createQuestionnaire();

        expect(questionnaireService.createQuestionnaire).toBeCalled();
        expect(response).toMatch(createdQuestionnaire);
    }

    it('Should create a new questionnaire', async () => {
        jest.doMock('./request-service', () =>
            jest.fn(() => ({
                post: () => createdQuestionnaire
            }))
        );

        const response = await questionnaireService.createQuestionnaire();

        expect(requestService.post).toBeCalled();
        expect(response).toMatch(createdQuestionnaire);
    }
});
```

All of the above yield the same error: `RequestError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND some_token some_token:443` which sounds like it's being thrown by the 'GOT' module not finding a url to hit. Can someone shed some light on how to get this to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a `require("somemodule")` it loads this module and executes it, so it executes `require` calls inside this module. Then all the modules are cached, so whenever you make a `require` again, it doesn't execute again, and returns already cached dependencies.

When you do `doMock`, you need to reset this cache, and make new `require` in your test for everything, that depends on mocked module.

```
    jest.doMock('./questionnaire-service', () =>
        jest.fn(() => ({
            createQuestionnaire: () => createdQuestionnaire
        }))
    );
    jest.resetModules();
    const questionnaireService = require(`questionnaire-service`)();

    const response = await questionnaireService.createQuestionnaire();
```